# change the font color from activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a java code for an apk. I want to change the color from java activity

```
 try {
   String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       s = s + 
               "User : "+json.getString("username")+"\n"+
               "Send : "+json.getString("time")+
               " & "+json.getString("date")+"\n"+
```

Now, I want to set 2 different color, for the `"user"` one color and `json.getString("username")` a different color as well as font weight, bold or not.

and my XML code is

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/result"
android:background="#2E2EFE"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:textColor="#F3F781"
android:textSize="24dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="20sp"        
android:text="TextView"/>
```

But I do not want to change the color from XML

Comment: youcan access the `result` `textView` in your code and call `setTextColor(Color.Red)` from your code

Comment: If I add `setTextColor(Color.Red)`, then it will change the full option, the results come from mysql, and when I set it, then the full text will  change

Comment: so what you are intended to do ?